# Table in php is not being created when ran through the query

Tags: php, mysql

I did this earlier and it worked just fine and I even brought in another table and it was created just fine. I am stuck.

Here is the table that is not working.

```
<?php
include_once('dbconx.php');

$tbl_pages = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pages (
              id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              label VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
              title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
              body TEXT NOT NULL,
              slug VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
              create TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
              updated TIMESTAMP NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY(id),
)";

$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $tbl_pages);
if ($query === TRUE) {
    echo "<h3>Pages table created OK :) </h3>";
} else {
    echo "<h3>Pages table NOT created :( </h3>";
}

 ?>
```

Comment: do u get any exception? if you do, can you print it out?

Comment: How would I do that ? All I know is that in my if statement it returned "Pages table NOT created :("

Comment: just for debugging, *if* there's an execption, you can use this refference http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp and then print it to the screen. or you can also run this query manualy using any mysql client

Comment: I ran it in the cmd and got:               ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
              updated TIMESTAMP NULL,
              P' at line 7

Answer (score 2):

One of your field names is a MySQL reserved words `create`. Try changing the field name to something like `created`. See [MySQL Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

You also have an extra comma after the primary key definition.

Try this query:

```
$tbl_pages = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pages (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    label VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated TIMESTAMP NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)";
```

You can also echo `mysqli_error` if it fails so you can see details of the error.

Comment: That did the trick. Just had to changed create to created and delete the extra comma. Thank you so much